# Postman and java call for 400 Bad request

Tags: json, spring, rest, postman

```html
//this body call gives 400 bad request
{
"name": "Ben"
}

//but only ben in body of the postman goes sucessfully
Ben


//in java getting 400 Bad request same as I was getting in postman
JSONObject jv = new JSONObject();
jv.put("name", "ben");
```

I was passing raw body as below in postman and I was getting 400 Bad request
{
"name": "Ben"
}
but when I passed only Ben (without quotation and parenthesis) in body of the postman the POST call went through successfully. I though body of the postman needs to be in key-value pair. Also in Java class I'm getting 400 bad request (same as I was getting in postman). This is what I'm doing in Java class JSONObject passV = new JSONObject(); passV.put("name", "Ben"). I don't know why postman call is working with Ben and same call not working in java class. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

400 error bad request with postman and Spring Boot API, in my case, happend for three reasons:

1. The first, is that the json format for the request is wrong, like sending:

   ```
    { key: value }
   ```

Or:

```
    { "key" : "value"
```

This is clarely not you case.

2. The second cause was sending the keys different from what the object was expecting.For example:

   ```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> save(@RequestResponse @Valid ClassOfReciveObject reciveObject){

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("OK");

    }
   ```

If the ClassOfObjectRecived has properties :

```
    {
        public String age;
        public String name;
    }
```

And you are sending in postman others keys, you will get a bad Request

```
    {
         "country":"Brazil",
         "Continent":"America"
    }
```

3. The third case i got this error was because of the private access modifier for the atributes of this class, change it for public, or find ways to resolve it

   ```
    public class ClassOfObjectRecived {
        public String param1;
        public String param2;
    }
   ```